# How to move multiple lines in a google sheet onto just 1 based on the date?

Tags: split, pivot, google-sheets-formula, substitution, flatten

I have many rows with data like below. I would like to end up with rows that have a single date in one column and the next column contains concatenated info of the other rows, like so:

1/20/2022   Telmisartan Missed Bisoprolol Missed
1/19/2022   Rosuvastatin Missed Amlodipine Missed Clopidogrel Missed Telmisartan Taken Bisoprolol Taken

RAW DATA:
Date    Status
1/20/2022   Telmisartan Missed
1/20/2022   Bisoprolol Missed
1/19/2022   Rosuvastatin Missed

1/19/2022   Clopidogrel Missed
1/19/2022   Telmisartan Taken
1/19/2022   Bisoprolol Taken
1/18/2022   Rosuvastatin Missed

1/18/2022   Clopidogrel Missed
1/18/2022   Telmisartan Taken
1/18/2022   Bisoprolol Taken
1/17/2022   Rosuvastatin Missed

1/17/2022   Clopidogrel Missed
1/17/2022   Telmisartan Taken
1/17/2022   Bisoprolol Taken

Comment: What date do you want? unique(), min or max?

Comment: Player0 answered it with MAX. That's the result I needed to make a list for my doctor's visit :-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(QUERY(A2:B; 
 "select max(B) where B is not null group by B pivot A");;9^9))); 
 " "; "×"; 1); "×"))
```

[image]